# Keep from a list only those with a delimiter

Tags: python

I have a list which is called `mylist`

and the data has this format

```
[['machine/learning', 'machine'], ['learning', 'machine/learning']]
```

How is it possible to keep in the list only the tokens which have inside them this character `'/'`

Expected output

```
[['machine//////////learning'], ['machine//////////learning']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a nested list comprehension pair:

```
myList = [['machine//////////learning', 'machine'], ['learning', 'machine//////////learning']]
check = '//////////'

myList = [[y for y in x if check in y] for x in myList]

print(myList)
```

Result:

```
[['machine//////////learning'], ['machine//////////learning']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want those that have a single '/' or the bunch of slashes '///////' together.

But, you can loop though the list and check if each value has the delimiter or not, and add it to a new list.

Somthing like this:

```py
list = [['machine//////////learning', 'machine'], ['learning','machine//////////learning']]
newlist = []
for inner_list in list:
    for l in inner_list:
        if ('//////////' in l):
            newlist.append(l)
print(newlist) #should be the ones with '//////////'
```

It could be better, but this has the idea.

Comment: @Steve answer is more neater.

Answer (score 1):

The most readable way would be to use python `filter` & `map` functionality

```
def valid(s):
    return '//////////' in s

def filter_valid(l):
    return list(filter(valid, l))    

filtered = list(map(filter_valid, my_list))
```

It could also be written as a **one liner** if one wishes:

```
list(map(lambda l: list(filter(lambda s: key in s, l)), my_list))
```

Comment: Why do you say "best"?  What makes this method superior to the others?  The main thing your solution seems to do is use up more space than mine would on the code page.

Comment: It is optimized for readability - the reduce map directives are commonly used in many languages and describe very well the operation that is being done